# Ubuntu 18.4 LTS, Snap Applications fail to run

Tags: linux

On my laptop, I can install an run snap applications just fine. However, I have an Ubuntu PC at my workplace where I can install the snap application but I can't run these applications. So far I found that on my laptop the home directory is **/home/username** but on my work PC it's pointing to **/export/home/username**. I think the issue is this weird path. But I am not sure.

When I run a snap application through the terminal, I get the following error. For example, running lepton

`$ lepton
cannot create user data directory: /export/home/username/snap/lepton/1: Read-only file system`

Answer (score 2):

You can bind mount custom home directory back to your regular directory (`mount --bind /source /destination`) and this should allow you to have the desired data layout and the ability to execute snaps.